# Haskell beginner - defining and using a type

Tags: haskell

I am trying to do the equivalent of this correctly working code :

```
len   :: [a] -> Int 
len [] = 0 
len (x:xs) = 1 + len xs
```

But for the type MyList that I am defining as :

```
data MyList a = Nil | Cons a (MyList a)
```

Here is my attempt :

```
mylen :: (MyList a) -> Int
mylen Nil = 0
mylen (Cons a (MyList a)) = 1 + mylen (MyList a)
```

But I get these errors:

> Conflicting definitions for ‘a’
>   
> Not in scope: data constructor ‘MyList’

I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: Why do you think you need to write `MyList a` in the `Cons`-pattern matching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your (reasonable) definition of `MyList`:

```
data MyList a = Nil | Cons a (MyList a)
```

...states that there are two constructors.

1. `Nil` (taking no arguments), and
2. `Cons`, which takes two arguments: the first of type `a`, the second of type `MyList a`

So to pattern match, you have to write something like `Cons item rest`, e.g.

```
mylen :: (MyList a) -> Int
mylen Nil = 0
mylen (Cons item rest) = 1 + mylen rest
```

But since you never use `item`, it is customary to replace it with `_`.

Notice how `a`, `Int` and `MyList a` are types. On the other hand, `item`, `0` and `1`, `rest`, and even `Nil` and `Cons item rest` are all instances of those types.

Comment: BTW, wouldn't it be nice to match Cons first, and then only write `mylen _ = 0`?

Comment: @bipll While that is marginally shorter code, it does throw away the ability to get a warning from the compiler to update the definition of `mylen` when the definition of `MyList` changes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
  mylen :: MyList a -> Int
  mylen Nil = 0
  mylen (Cons _ next) = 1 + mylen next
```